# Python random square movement not working

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, random

I am trying to make a square that repeatedly moves forward a random amount of pixels, but here's what happens:

```
gui.move(ai, random.randint(10, 100, 10), 0) # gui is the tkinter canvas
```

then I get:

```
TypeError: randint() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

How can I have 3 parameters but keep it the same?

Comment: `random.randint` has two parameters (3 because of implicit `self`). What's the third - "10" parameter supposed to be?

Comment: The steps. I read that random can be ```random.randint(start, end, step)```

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: There is nothing in the official documentation about a third parameter.  Please provide your source.

Comment: Oops, I was doing it wrong! That's why it wasn't working!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that ```randint``` doesn't have a third parameter.

Comment: `random.randrange(10, 100, 10)` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.randint` takes two arguments from you, the third is a `self`. If you want to apply a step param, you might want a `random.choice` from a `range`:

```py
import random

random.choice(range(10, 100, 10))
90
```

Where `range` allows for `(start, stop, step)`

Comment: This works! I just multiplied the ```randint``` by 10, but this probably works better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

> random.randint(a, b) Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.
> Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

Comment: Sorry, not quite following